# Declaration of variable in C++

Tags: c++, variables, coding-style, declaration

Recently I saw a quite old code in C++, where `int var(12)` was used instead of `int var=12`. Why does it work? And should I avoid writing this style of declaration?

Answer (score 0):

There are three ways of initializing variables are valid in C++.

**type identifier = initial_value;**

For example, to declare a variable of type int called x and initialize it to a value of zero from the same moment it is declared, we can write:

```
int a=5;               // initial value: 5
```

**type identifier (initial_value);**

A second method, known as constructor initialization (introduced by the C++ language), encloses the initial value between parentheses (()):

```
int b(3);              // initial value: 3
```

**type identifier {initial_value};**

Finally, a third method, known as uniform initialization, similar to the above, but using curly braces ({}) instead of parentheses (this was introduced by the revision of the C++ standard, in 2011):

```
int c{2};              // initial value: 2
```

You should check [Documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/variables/) section **Initialization of variables**

Comment: They are not equivalent.`()` will perform certain narrowing conversions.

Comment: `int a{1.0}` is an error. `int a(1.0)` is legal. They are not the same.